# How to add background color for ODD and EVEN rows in PHP?

Tags: css, styles

I want to add background color for each odd rows(#e5e8e8) and even rows (#b9b8bb) in CSS.

```
for ($i = 2; $i <= $arrayCount; $i++) {

        $_SESSION["a"] = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["A"]);

        $_SESSION["b"] = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["B"]);

        $_SESSION["c"] = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["C"]);

        $_SESSION["d"] = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["D"]);

        $_SESSION["e"] = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["E"]);

        $_SESSION["f"] = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["F"]);

        $_SESSION["g"] = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["G"]);


                       echo '<!-- table content - start --> ';
                       echo ' <!-- ROW 1 -->';
                        echo '<tr>';
                            echo '<td width="10" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;">';
                                echo '<img src="http://ebiz.pmgasia.com/web/hp/HP_ProTrain_Monthly_eDM/ID/2017/February/images/x.gif" width="10" height="1" style="display:block;border:none;"/>';
                           echo ' </td>';

                            echo '<td width="164" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;" valign="middle">';
                                echo '<table width="164" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">';
                                    echo '<tr>';
                                        echo '<td height="15" style="font-size:0px;line-height:0px;"><img src="http://ebiz.pmgasia.com/web/hp/HP_ProTrain_Monthly_eDM/ID/2017/February/images/x.gif" width="1" height="15" style="display:block;border:none;"/></td>';
                                   echo ' </tr>';
                                    echo '<tr>';

                                        echo '<td width="114" valign="middle" align="left">';
                                            echo '<font style="font-family: HP Simplified, arial, sans-serif; font-size:15px;color:#000000;font-weight:normal; line-height:16px;">';

                                                 echo $_SESSION["a"];
                                            echo '</font>';
                                       echo ' </td>';

                                       echo ' <td width="50" valign="middle" align="right">';

                                        echo '</td>';
                                    echo '</tr>';
                                    echo '<tr>';
                                        echo '<td height="15" style="font-size:0px;line-height:0px;"><img src="http://ebiz.pmgasia.com/web/hp/HP_ProTrain_Monthly_eDM/ID/2017/February/images/x.gif" width="1" height="15" style="display:block;border:none;"/></td>';
                                   echo ' </tr>';
                                echo '</table>';
                            echo '</td>';

                           echo ' <td width="10" style="border-right: 1px solid #ffffff;border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;">';
                                echo '<img src="http://ebiz.pmgasia.com/web/hp/HP_ProTrain_Monthly_eDM/ID/2017/February/images/x.gif" width="10" height="1" style="display:block;border:none;"/>';
                            echo '</td>';
                            echo '<td width="10" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;">';
                                echo '<img src="http://ebiz.pmgasia.com/web/hp/HP_ProTrain_Monthly_eDM/ID/2017/February/images/x.gif" width="10" height="1" style="display:block;border:none;"/>';
                            echo '</td>';
                            echo '<td width="164" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;" valign="middle">';
                                echo '<table width="164" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">';
                                    echo '<tr>';
                                        echo '<td height="15" style="font-size:0px;line-height:0px;"><img src="http://ebiz.pmgasia.com/web/hp/HP_ProTrain_Monthly_eDM/ID/2017/February/images/x.gif" width="1" height="15" style="display:block;border:none;"/></td>';
                                   echo ' </tr>';
                                    echo '<tr>';
                                        echo '<td width="114" valign="middle" align="left">';
                                            echo '<font style="font-family: HP Simplified, arial, sans-serif; font-size:15px;color:#000000;font-weight:normal; line-height:16px;">';
                                              echo $_SESSION["b"];

                                            echo '</font>';
                                        echo '</td>';
                                        echo '<td width="50" valign="middle" align="right">';
                                            echo '<font style="font-family: HP Simplified, arial, sans-serif; font-size:15px;color:#000000;font-weight:normal; line-height:16px;">';
                                              echo $_SESSION["c"];
                                            echo '</font>';
                                        echo '</td>';
                                   echo ' </tr>';
                                    echo '<tr>';
                                        echo '<td height="15" style="font-size:0px;line-height:0px;"><img src="http://ebiz.pmgasia.com/web/hp/HP_ProTrain_Monthly_eDM/ID/2017/February/images/x.gif" width="1" height="15" style="display:block;border:none;"/></td>';
                                    echo '</tr>';
                                echo '</table>';
                            echo '</td>';
                            echo '<td width="10" style="border-right: 1px solid #ffffff;border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;">';
                                echo '<img src="http://ebiz.pmgasia.com/web/hp/HP_ProTrain_Monthly_eDM/ID/2017/February/images/x.gif" width="10" height="1" style="display:block;border:none;"/>';
                            echo '</td>';
                            echo '<td width="10" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;">';
                                echo '<img src="http://ebiz.pmgasia.com/web/hp/HP_ProTrain_Monthly_eDM/ID/2017/February/images/x.gif" width="10" height="1" style="display:block;border:none;"/>';
                            echo '</td>';
                            echo '<td width="164" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;" valign="middle">';
                                echo '<table width="164" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">';
                                    echo '<tr>';
                                        echo '<td height="15" style="font-size:0px;line-height:0px;"><img src="http://ebiz.pmgasia.com/web/hp/HP_ProTrain_Monthly_eDM/ID/2017/February/images/x.gif" width="1" height="15" style="display:block;border:none;"/></td>';
                                   echo ' </tr>';
                                    echo '<tr>';
                                        echo '<td width="114" valign="middle" align="left">';
                                            echo '<font style="font-family: HP Simplified, arial, sans-serif; font-size:15px;color:#000000;font-weight:normal; line-height:16px;">';
                                            echo $_SESSION["d"];

                                            echo '</font>';
                                       echo '</td>';
                                        echo '<td width="50" valign="middle" align="right">';
                                            echo '<font style="font-family: HP Simplified, arial, sans-serif; font-size:15px;color:#000000;font-weight:normal; line-height:16px;">';
                                             echo $_SESSION["e"];
                                           echo '</font>';
                                        echo '</td>';
                                    echo '</tr>';
                                    echo '<tr>';
                                        echo '<td height="15" style="font-size:0px;line-height:0px;"><img src="http://ebiz.pmgasia.com/web/hp/HP_ProTrain_Monthly_eDM/ID/2017/February/images/x.gif" width="1" height="15" style="display:block;border:none;"/></td>';
                                    echo '</tr>';
                                echo '</table>';
                            echo '</td>';
                            echo '<td width="10" style="border-right: 1px solid #ffffff;border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;">';
                                echo '<img src="http://ebiz.pmgasia.com/web/hp/HP_ProTrain_Monthly_eDM/ID/2017/February/images/x.gif" width="10" height="1" style="display:block;border:none;"/>';
                            echo '</td>';

                            echo '<td width="10" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;">';
                                echo '<img src="http://ebiz.pmgasia.com/web/hp/HP_ProTrain_Monthly_eDM/ID/2017/February/images/x.gif" width="10" height="1" style="display:block;border:none;"/>';
                            echo '</td>';
                            echo '<td width="164" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;" valign="middle">';
                                echo '<table width="164" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">';
                                    echo '<tr>';
                                        echo '<td height="15" style="font-size:0px;line-height:0px;"><img src="http://ebiz.pmgasia.com/web/hp/HP_ProTrain_Monthly_eDM/ID/2017/February/images/x.gif" width="1" height="15" style="display:block;border:none;"/></td>';
                                    echo '</tr>';
                                    echo '<tr>';
                                        echo '<td width="114" valign="middle" align="left">';
                                            echo '<font style="font-family: HP Simplified, arial, sans-serif; font-size:15px;color:#000000;font-weight:normal; line-height:16px;">';
                                             echo $_SESSION["f"];

                                            echo '</font>';
                                       echo ' </td>';
                                        echo '<td width="50" valign="middle" align="right">';
                                            echo '<font style="font-family: HP Simplified, arial, sans-serif; font-size:15px;color:#000000;font-weight:normal; line-height:16px;">';
                                               echo $_SESSION["g"];
                                           echo ' </font>';
                                        echo '</td>';
                                   echo ' </tr>';
                                   echo ' <tr>';
                                        echo '<td height="15" style="font-size:0px;line-height:0px;"><img src="http://ebiz.pmgasia.com/web/hp/HP_ProTrain_Monthly_eDM/ID/2017/February/images/x.gif" width="1" height="15" style="display:block;border:none;"/></td>';
                                   echo ' </tr>';
                                echo '</table>';
                           echo ' </td>';
                            echo '<td width="10" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;">';
                                echo '<img src="http://ebiz.pmgasia.com/web/hp/HP_ProTrain_Monthly_eDM/ID/2017/February/images/x.gif" width="10" height="1" style="display:block;border:none;"/>';
                            echo '</td>';

                        echo '</tr>';

                        echo '<!-- ROW 1 - END -->';


   }
```

Here I want to add background color for each odd rows(#e5e8e8) and even rows (#b9b8bb) in PHP dynamically to this row which I wrote inside the for loop.My above given table code was created for Email template.So it has lot of  and s.so ODD and EVEN options not working properly.Any suggestions.Thanks in advance

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: I just edited my post..Please help.thanks in advance

Comment: Crikey! Why so many `echos`?

Comment: My above given table code was created for Email template.So it has lot of <tr> and <td>s.Thats why I used more echos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So without delving into your code to correct it here's a general example as it is a CSS question realistically.. So to do this you need to use `nth-child()`. Here's an example:

```css
tr:nth-child(odd)  { background-color:#e5e8e8; }
tr:nth-child(even)  { background-color:#b9b8bb; }
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td> Row 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Row 2
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: How to use the following code inside PHP:                                                    tr:nth-child(odd)  { background-color:#e5e8e8; }
tr:nth-child(even)  { background-color:#b9b8bb; }

Comment: My above given table code was created for Email template.So it has lot of <tr> and <td>s.so ODD and EVEN options not working properly.Any suggestions.Thanks in advance